# Namspace System.IO.Compression with class ZipFile

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unzip

what am i missing? I have the namespace declared and then have this line in my controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(ScormUploadViewModel model)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    if (model.ScormPackageFile != null)
    {
      string destinationDirectoryName = "c:\\TSFPreview\\Zinc\\Web\\Project\\ScormPackages";
      ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(model.ScormPackageFile, destinationDirectoryName);
    }
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

i get "ZipFile does not exist in the current context"??

Comment: Are you sure that the project and the IIS app pool targets .NET 4.5?

Comment: i checked in control panel, programs and featurs and there is .net 4.5 in the list

Comment: That's not what I asked.

Comment: oops sorry, then i dont understand your question? how do I check that please?

Comment: this in web.config:   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> ??

Comment: you can update References in Project file directly <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
Rebuild proj

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the IIS application pool to run .NET 4.5 since that class was not available earlier.

Here is an instruction: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754523(v=WS.10).aspx

The `<compilation` instruction is only useful when debugging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff400235(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: im sorry but i cannot just change it we run .net 4.0.  please help im stuck and I must get this going. :) all i want is to unzip a file into a directory in asp.net MVC 3 with .net 4.0

Comment: Then you have to use something which exists in .NET 4.0 (`ZipFile` doesn't), for instance `GZipStream`